# get data from array nested object in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

data=[{"id": 7, "name": "Colleen Watson"}]

I want to get data like this

**data.name**="Collen Watson"

Comment: you can use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method.

Comment: you need an index of the array, like `data[0].name`.

Comment: clarify the problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Sample array being

```
data=[
  {"id": 1, "name": "Colleen Watson"}, 
  {"id": 2, "name": "Name2"},
  {"id": 3, "name": "Name3"}
]
```

If you want the object based on property value,

```
// Gets the object which has the name property as "Coleen Watson"
const foundObject = data.find(o => o.name === 'Colleen Watson');
```

If you want the name property value of an object on a specific index

```
// Gets the name property value of the first object
const foundName = data[0].name
```